# How to get str from a POST method and save it in the db and return a message with a str in django?

Tags: python, django

The contents of the POST request:
Task/name
The received object is just a string and a Task object must be created using this string. This string is equal to the same name field in the Task object.

This page is located at the following URL:
http: // localhost: 8000 / tasks
After adding the task, the following message should be displayed to the user:

For example, if a task called 'Study for 2 hours' is added, the following message should be displayed to the user:

Task Created: 'Study for 2 hours'

**model** :

```
from django.db import models


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**view:**

```
from .models import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


@csrf_exempt
def list_create_tasks(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        all_task = Task(name=name)
        all_task.save()
        return HttpResponse(f"Task Created: {name}")
```

It does not work according to the view. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you explain the issue you are facing? The code seems ok, and working on my end.

Comment: Right! How you are making POST request?

Comment: in postman key: name, value: Study for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could quickly create and save a Task object by doing something like this:

```
Task.objects.create (name = name)
```